# Why does #define not require a semicolon?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was writing some test code in **C**. By mistake I had inserted a `;` after a `#define`, which gave me errors. Why is a semicolon not required for `#define`s?

More specifically :

**Method 1: works**

```
const int MAX_STRING = 256;

int main(void) {
    char buffer[MAX_STRING];
}
```

**Method 2: Does not work - compilation error.**

```
#define MAX_STRING 256;

int main(void) {
    char buffer[MAX_STRING];
}
```

What is the reason of the different behavior of those codes? Are those both MAX_STRINGs not constants?

Comment: View the preprocessor output and the answer will be staring you in the face.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis yeah, it is the easiest way `cpp prog_name.c | tail` say it all.

Comment: Trick: compile with `-E -dD` flags. `-E` flag stops the compiler *after* preprocessing phase (does not compile). `-dD` flag indicates the preprocessor to leave the preprocessor directives on the file, although their usage is still processed.

Comment: C does not have symbolics constants (except for _enum-constants_). `const` qualified **variables** are no constants in C. And `#define`d names are no constants either.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`#define` is a [**preprocessor directive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), not a *statement* or *declaration* as defined by the C grammar (both of those are required to end with a semicolon). The rules for the syntax of each one are different.

Answer (score 42):

```
#define MAX_STRING 256;
```

means:

whenever you find MAX_STRING when preprocessing, replace it with `256;`. In your case it'll make method 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_STRING 256;

int main(void) {
    char buffer [256;];
}
```

which isn't valid syntax. Replace

```
#define MAX_STRING 256;
```

with

```
#define MAX_STRING 256
```

The difference between your two codes is that in first method you declare a constant equal to `256` but in the second code you define `MAX_STRING` to stand for `256;` in your source file.

> The #define directive is used to define values or macros that are used by the preprocessor to manipulate the program source code before it is compiled. Because preprocessor definitions are substituted before the compiler acts on the source code, any errors that are introduced by #define are difficult to trace.

The syntax is:

```
#define CONST_NAME VALUE
```

if there is a `;` at the end, it's considered as a part of `VALUE`.

to understand how exactly `#define`s work, try defining:

```
#define FOREVER for(;;)
...
    FOREVER {
         /perform something forever.
    }
```

Interesting remark by [John Hascall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2040863/john-hascall):

> Most compilers will give you a way to see the output after the preprocessor phase, this can aid with debugging issues like this.

In [`gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) it can be done with flag `-E`.

Comment: Most compilers will give you a way to see the output after the preprocessor phase, this can aid with debugging issues like this.

Answer (score 17):

`define` is a preprocessor directive, and is a simple replacement, it is not a declaration.

BTW, as a replacement it may contain some `;` as part of it:

```
// Ugly as hell, but valid 
#define END_STATEMENT ;

int a = 1 END_STATEMENT // preprocessed to -> int a = 1;
```

Answer (score 13):

Both constants? No.

The first method does not produce a *constant* in C language. Const-qualified variables do not qualify as constants in C. Your first method works only because *past-C99 C* compilers support variable-length arrays (VLA). Your `buffer` is a VLA in the first case specifically because `MAX_STRING` is *not* a constant. Try declaring the same array in file scope and you'll get an error, since VLAs are not allowed in file scope.

The second method can be used to assign names to constant values in C, but you have to do it properly. The `;` in macro definition should not be there. Macros work through textual substitution and you don't want to substitute that extra `;` into your array declaration. The proper way to define that macro would be

```
#define MAX_STRING 256
```

In C language, when it comes to defining proper named constants, you are basically limited to macros and enums. Don't try to use `const` "constants", unless you really know that it will work for your purposes.

Comment: additionally, VLAs are not allowed at file scope since they must be dynamically allocated (stack or `malloc`).

Answer (score 11):

Because that is how the syntax was decided for the ***precompiler directives***.

Only ***statements*** end with a `;` in c/c++, ***`#define` is a pre-processor directive and not a statement***.

Answer (score 11):

The second version does not define a constant as far as the language is concerned, just a substitution rule for a block of text. Once the *preprocessor* has done it's job, the *compiler* sees

`char buffer [256;];`

which is not syntactically valid.

The moral of the story: prefer the `const int MAX_STRING = 256;` way as that helps you, the compiler, and the debugger.

Comment: I'm not sure, how does it help the debugger ?

Comment: You ever tried to debug a load of code with macros in it?

Comment: In general case `const int MAX_STRING = 256;` is *not* a viable approach in C language, since such `MAX_STRING` would not be a *constant* in C and would not be allowed to be used where a constant expression is required.

Comment: Yes there are some hidden depths here: C does handle `const` differently to C++ but the former also supports variable length arrays.

Comment: @Bathsheba: VLA does not really save the day here. There are great many other contexts where C requires constants: case labels, non-local array declarations, bit-field width, static initializers etc. None of these contexts would accept a `const int` "constant". In other words, every context that expects a compile-time value will reject a `const int` since in C this is not considered a compile-time value.

Comment: `enum { MAX_STRING = 256 };` solves both problems. The only reason to use `#define` is if you need to use the value in preprocessor arithmetic (or if the value is outside the range of `int` in which case `enum` cannot be used portably).

Answer (score 1):

This preprocessor directive:

```
#define MAX_STRING 256;
```

tells the preprocessor to replace all `MAX_STRING`s with `256;` - and *with the semicolon*. Preprocessor statements don't need a semicolon at the end. If you put one, the preprocessor actually thinks you mean it with a semicolon.

If you are confused with `#define`s for constants, `const int` would probably be easier to comprehend.

If you want to learn more on how to properly use these preprocessor directives, try looking at [this website.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

Comment: But a `const int` is *not* a constant in C.